# Cannot implicitly convert from string to string[]

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to copy values in string array into a `DataRow`, it throws an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert from string to string[]

The code:

```
DataRow dr = null;
ddcontent[i] = strfinalstartweek[i] + " - " + strfinalendweek[i] + "-- $" + openingbid;
// ddcontent is the string array
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    dr.ItemArray = ddcontent[i];
    ListItem item = new ListItem();
    item.Text = NullHandler.NullHandlerForString(dr["OpeningBid"], string.Empty);
    ddweek.Items.Add(item);
}
```

What do you guys think is wrong in here.. tried lot of ways trying.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Needs more context - What type is `ddcontent`? What type is `dr`?

Comment: The exception usually contains a reference to the line in your source code that is causing the problem. It would be of great help if you could highlight the line that generates the error.

Comment: On which line do you get the error. The stackTrace will help.

Comment: Can you add the types for the different items?  It seems to me from the error message that dr is of type String[][].

Comment: I'm going to guess that ddcontent[i] is returning a string and trying to assign a value to dr.ItemArray, which is a string array. Not enough context though.

Comment: @Jason - yeah it's probably supposed to be `dr.ItemArray[i] = ddcontent[i]`

Comment: I edited the question. ddcontent is the string array that has 12 values.. And dr is Datarow.

Comment: `What do you guys think is wrong in here?` That's easy, you're trying to convert a `string` into a `string-array`. Of course this can't be done, so check all your types. And If I'd have to guess, then the problem is the line `dr.ItemArray = ddcontent[i];`. `ItemArray` is most likely of type `string[]`, but `ddcontent[i]` is a simple `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dr.ItemArray = ddcontent[i];
```

`ItemArray` is of type `object[]` so that line won't work.  A `string` can't be converted to an array of `object`s.  Based on the text of the error, however, I wonder if there is another type mismatch in the code as well.  Can you show which line contains the error?

Comment: dr.ItemArray = ddcontent[i]; this line  contains the error. Thank you

Comment: @Ram: Chances are (and this is based on the limited code we're seeing, so you'll want to confirm the logic yourself), what you probably want to do is: `dr.ItemArray[i] = ddcontent[i];`.

Comment: i am sorry David, I am trying to save the string array values into the datarow. Then, show it in the dropdown. This is the aim. When i changed it to dr.ItemArray[i] = ddcontent[i];there is no error but has an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: @Ram: Oops, I missed the fact that the `DataRow` is null here.  It's not initialized and therefore has no `ItemArray` property.  Why are you using a `DataRow`?  It's being declared here, and you attempt to populate it here, but what is its intended use?  And what is its data structure that you're trying to populate?  Why not just create the ListItems from the string array?

Comment: @David: List Items? New concept that i should see.. I am new for asp.net. Learning it.. I will see what List Item does.

Comment: Below worked for me. Just tried to bind it. Thanks @David for your time to letting me know. Appreciate that! Thanks again..              ddweek.DataSource = ddcontent; ddweek.DataBind();

Comment: @Ram: Glad I could help!  Note that there's more you can do when binding to a DataSource like that.  You're currently binding to a string array, so both the Text and Value properties of the DropDownList will be the string of each item.  You can also bind it to an array of custom objects (or an IList of custom objects, etc.) and set the DataTextField and DataValueField of the DropDownList to the corresponding properties on those objects for the Text and Value of the DropDownList items.

Answer (score 0):

Is ddcontent an array of strings (the data rows)? If you want to chop each row up to fit into a data row, you have to use the  [string.Split method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided it seems that ddcontent[i] is a string and you are trying to assign it to a property - ItemArray - that expects an a array. To fix this you need to either:

Move this line outside your loop and assign the ddcontent array dirctly to the ItemArray. But note that you ddcontent has to have the SAME number of items as columns in your DataRow.

```
   dr.ItemArray = ddcontent;
   for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
   {
      ListItem item = new ListItem();
      item.Text = NullHandler.NullHandlerForString(dr["OpeningBid"], string.Empty);
      ddweek.Items.Add(item);
   }
```

Or in the loop assign the items using the Item indexer

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
   {
      dr.Item[i] = ddcontent[i];
      ListItem item = new ListItem();
      item.Text = NullHandler.NullHandlerForString(dr["OpeningBid"], string.Empty);
      ddweek.Items.Add(item);
   }
```

Also, I am assuming that you are creating a new DataRow instance somewhere in your code after DataRow dr = null and before using the dr i.e. there is a line like this somewhere:

```
dr = dt.NewRow();
```

where `dt` is your datatable.